# "INNER JOIN" and "LEFT JOIN" with "GROUP BY"

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

My tables looks like this

```
sales
----------------------------------------------------------
id  ordernumber             quantity  category_id    price
1   402-9182243-8008368     1         3              22.95
2   406-3666671-8627555     2         3               6.95
3   303-1935495-5532309     1         1               7.95
4   171-5799800-1198702     1         2             159.95
5   403-2398078-4901169     2         2              18.95

category
--------------
id  name
1   bikes
2   shoes
3   planes

returns
--------------
id  ordernumber          quantity   costs
1   402-9182243-8008368  1          22.95   
2   402-9182243-8008368              5.95   // return shipping fee
```

And here is my query

```
    SELECT c.name,
           SUM(v.quantity) AS sold,               # wrong
           SUM(s.quantity * s.price) AS turnover, # wrong
           SUM(r.costs) AS returncosts,
      FROM sales AS s
INNER JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = s.category_id  
 LEFT JOIN returns AS r ON r.ordernumber = s.ordernumber 
  GROUP BY c.name
```

I have some inner joins with aggregate functions.
But I also need "return" with a "Left Join" (I think). 
And with Left Join, my aggregate functions dont work anymore. 
Left Join adds additional rows. Additional data, for sum().

I need a single query, so every column is sortable later. 
I would be happy about any help. Best Regards

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: try to use HAVING with LEFT JOIN.

Comment: If you are aggregating and there are many one-to-many relations involved, you must have a subquery for the aggregation of each relation.

Comment: I think that you have a typo in your example query, should SUM(t.costs) be SUM(r.costs)? That doesn't fix your issue, but makes the question make a little more sense.

Comment: @dmoore1181 thank you, I have fixed the typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a semi cartesian product because ordernumber is not unique in returns table.

We can see what's happening if we remove the aggregate functions and return the detail rows.

One possible approach is to pre-aggregate returns in an inline view, so that unique values of ordernumber are returned.

Assuming ordernumber is unique in sales table, then something like this:

```
SELECT c.name
     , SUM(s.quantity)                  AS sold
     , SUM(s.quantity * s.price)        AS turnover
     , SUM(r.returncosts)               AS returncosts
  FROM sales s
  JOIN categories c
    ON c.id = s.category_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN ( SELECT t.ordernumber 
              , SUM(t.costs) AS returncosts
           FROM returns t
          GROUP
             BY t.ordernumber
       ) r 
    ON r.ordernumber = s.ordernumber
 GROUP
    BY c.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sum the quantity separately from the `LEFT JOIN` in a `sub query` as follows:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.sold, t1.turnover, SUM(r.costs) AS returncosts  
FROM(
   SELECT c.name,
       SUM(s.quantity) AS sold,                
       SUM(s.quantity * s.price) AS turnover 
  FROM sales AS s
 INNER JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = s.category_id 
 GROUP BY name
)  t1
LEFT JOIN returns AS r ON r.ordernumber = s.ordernumber 
GROUP BY t1.name, t1.sold, t1.turnover
```

Comment: thank you, also a nice solution for upcoming problem